# Get 4x4 matrix input in multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, input, matrix

I'm trying to get a 4x4 matrix as a input.

Sample input:

> 1234 
>   5678
>   9124
>   3248

I've declared array 'a' as follows, so that i could insert/get the matrix value by specifying the indices like a[1][3], a[2][1] etc...

> a = [[0 for x in xrange(n+1)] for x in xrange(n+1)]

I've having difficulty in handling the input. i.e How to get the 16 elements in four lines, Four elements/line?

Comment: Are the inputs strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single digit/character inputs you can simply:

```
>>> a,b,c,d = str(input('>> '))
>> 1234
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'2'
>>> c
'3'
>>> d
'4'
```

This will achieve what you are looking for by asking the user for input 4 times:

```
lst =[]
for i in range(4):
    a,b,c,d= str(input('>> ')
    lst.append([a,b,c,d])
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be:

```
input_ = "1234 5678 9124 3248"

a = [list(s) for s in input_.split(" ")]

a == [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7', '8'], 
      ['9', '1', '2', '4'], ['3', '2', '4', '8']]
```

If you want the numbers to be integers, not strings, try:

```
a = [list(map(int, s)) for s in input_.split(" ")]

a == [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 1, 2, 4], [3, 2, 4, 8]]
```

Note that this will work only with single-digit integers.

If your inputs are lines in a file, you can split on the newline `"\n"` instead of the space `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []

for i in range(4):

    b = []

    for j in range(4):
        j = int(input("Enter Number in pocket [" + str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "]"))

        b.append(j)

    a.append(b)
print(" 4*4 Matrix is ......")

for i in range(4):

    for j in range(4):
        print(a[i][j], end=" ")

    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dist = [] 
for i in range(4):
    a, b, c, d = ("".join(map(str, input('>> ')))) 
    dist.append([int(a), int(b), int(c), int(d)])
```

correct code to get the 4*4 matrix , just change the name of the matrix variable in the snip i have name dist , after changing you are ready to go